# How get average value of all 15minutes candle within 4 hour candle

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

There are 16 15minutes candles in 4hour candle. How get average value of all 15minutes candle within a 4 hour candle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)
lower = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, '15', close)
avg = lower.avg()

if barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index, high, str.tostring(avg,format.mintick), color=color.aqua)
```

Comment: I want to add a value to last candle value. If I code 
weight = close + 100  
It add 100 to all past value. But I want to add only to last value. Please help me.

Comment: please accept the answer as correct if you feel it answered your original question. You can add only to the last value by adding barstate.isrealtime or barstate.islastconfirmedhistory

Comment: Dear, not clear. Suppose MA, how to code as above.  Please show how to use it

Comment: you want to plot the average ? or how to use the close + 100 you asked about

Comment: How to use the close + 100 only to last bar value for MA

Comment: I would write it in a new question so it can be useful for others as well and can have it's own answer

Comment: Question link is here.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76731531/how-to-add-a-value-only-to-last-candle-value-in-pine-v5